# Can someone please explain me how does this matlab code get the red channel of an image?

Tags: image, matlab, channel

here is the code

```
  img = imread('imageName.jpg');
  redChannel = img(:,:,1);
  blackColor = zeros(size(redChannel));
  redImage = cat(3,redChannel,blackColor,blackColor);
```

my thoughts are we first read the image and save it in a variable
then

we know that the image will be of 3 dimensions 512x512x3

the third dimension has to do with the channels

```
       1: red
       2: green
       3: blue
```

now the redChannel variable will take the red channel of the image

so, my question is, why can't I just use

```
       image(redChannel)
```

to show the image? the problem is it doesnt show me anything except for a red color

now he says

```
        blackColor = zeros(size(redChannel));
        redImage = cat(3,redChannel,blackColor,blackColor);
```

the blackColor has zeros everywhere and the size of this will be 512x512

which is the same as the size of each channel

about the cat, I don't understand why he's doing it....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take this image as an example:

[image]

`image(redChannel)` will display the red channel but it will truncate the values between 0 and 63. With the default color bar, the low values will be blue and the high values are red. Your problem is that all values above 63 are represented with the same red color:

[image]

`imagesc(redChannel)` will do the same thing but it will scale the color bar such that blue corresponds to the minimal values of redChannel and red corresponds to its maximal values (yellow-green are intermediate values):

[image]

`imshow(redChannel)` will show you the red channel, but in black and white (It will not have the 0-63 artefact) :

[image]

`image(redImage)` will show you the same information but in black and red, instead of black and white. Basically it removed the green and blue part in red, so you'll have only the red channel remaining displayed in red.
Actually `image` has a different behavior when the input has 1 channel or 3 channels.
When it has one channel, it truncates the values to 0-63 and display it with the blue-red colorbar. When it has 3 channels, it displays it as an RGB color image:

[image]

So in your case:

```
   redImage = cat(3,redChannel,blackColor,blackColor);
```

redImage concatenates three channels.
For the red (first) channel, it puts the red channel of your input image.
For the green and blue (second and third) channels, it put only zeros. So basically, `redImage` is like `img`, but the green and blue channels are set to zero.

Comment: +1. You might just want to explain what the `cat(3,...)` statement does.

Comment: thanks that was very useful and your explanation was clear :)